# Can I prevent a HorizontalScrollView from expanding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

One of my DialogFragment's layouts uses a `HorizontalScrollView` to horizontally scroll its child `LinearLayout`. Is there a way to lock its width into place so that it doesn't expand the width of the DialogFragment once the LinearLayout has been populated with items?

Here's what the `DialogFragment` looks like when it first loads:
[image: DialogFragment - First Load]

And here's what happens when the `LinearLayout` under the **Kanji** header is populated with items:
[image: DialogFramgnet - Items populated]

Everything scrolls fine once the items are populated, but I want to prevent the `DialogFragment` from expanding. Setting a fixed width on the root of the `HorizontalScrollView` prevented it from expanding, but I can't think of a good way to do so while taking into account the highly variable size of Android screens.

Here's some code for the area under **Kanji**:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_kanji"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Use `android:maxWidth` to a specific value or set it programmatically?  Would post as answer, but can't confirm right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired effect by setting the width of the `HorizontalScrollView` to whatever it was when the dialog first opened:

```
// Fix the size of the HorizontalScrollView so it doesn't expand
HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.grid_kanji_root);

int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (float) hsv.getHeight(), getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (float) hsv.getWidth(), getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

hsv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return measurements in pixels, which is why my `TypedValue`'s use `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` instead of `COMPLEX_UNIT_DP`.

Note that you can't do this in `onCreateDialog()` or `onResume()` since the width returned will be 0 (zero). I ended up running this code in the function that loads cursor results into the child `LinearLayout` with a global boolean that keeps track of whether or not I've already set the width - if it's `FALSE` (as when the dialog first loads), then I set the width and set the boolean to `TRUE`.

I also discovered that the `LayoutParams` you apply to a control must match the type of the *parent* element. Since my `HorizontalScrollView` is located inside of a `LinearLayout`, I had to apply `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to it instead of `HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams`. You'll get a **ClassCast Exception** otherwise.